# Decoherence from path integral perspective?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, decoherence

Suppose I computed a truly monstrous path integral of an entire double slit experiment - including the particle, the measurement apparatus, the environment, and the experimenter - in order to compute the following:

The probability of an experimenter observing the apparatus registering a particle at position x2, given that the particle actually interacted at x1.

I should in theory get a probability of near zero when x1 does NOT equal x2, right? Would this in principle convey the same idea as decoherence? Why or why not?

Comment: Observed at X2 when it happened at X1, is that an error of measurement? Having a coherent system/particle and a huge path integral means we can make observations consistent with the laws of physics (and probability) for the well defined system. It's also possible that the observer thought they observed something and nothing really happened.  Decoherence happens to the system/particle and the particle is no more .... it has become part of a much bigger random system that was not part of the original experiment.  Hopefully in a well designed experiment we observe most of the decoherences.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand this answer. I'm asking if the loss of coherence between trajectories where the particle landed at x1 and x2 can be understood from a path integral framework.

Comment: It's possible my wording was poor.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question but, .... Maybe as an example lets take a simple single photon in a DSE.... the photon starts at the source (emitted), it has become coherent with the system geometry (i.e. source position, slit positions, screen position (and the EM field)) and its path has been cast in stone at this point (assuming nothing in the system changes).  The photon exists in this coherent state for a brief time, it gets absorbed (or decoheres) at the screen. The path int just tells the probability of the photon hitting the screen at positions along the screen.